# How to stop air leaking from this part of HVAC?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

Air is leaking out of the back of this Goodman HVAC unit. What would I need to reseal this part? It’s where the condensate drain line connects.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of that glob of putty and get some foil AC duct tape and some AC duct mastic from your home store. Put a few layers of the tape  covering the hole and up against the tubing. Then cover the tape with the mastic and smooth it out.

A better way would be to remove the tubing and replace it with PVC piping. Leave an unglued coupling right outside the air handler in case you have to open up the drain pipe for cleaning. Use the tape and mastic same as above.

Comment: Or if the tube can be removed (temporarily), get a rubber grommet with a nice tight fit.

Comment: @Huesmann  It looks like the installer really butchered making the hole so finding a grommet that size might be hard but yes, normally that would be a great idea.

Comment: While I agree that the hole *looks* a bit hacked (hard to tell with the little visible), it's always possible to either hog the hole out (unibit?) to a regular circular shape.  Or get another piece of flat sheet metal and drill a good hole in *that,* then use the AC tape and tape the flat sheet over the janky hole (well sealed, of course).

Comment: @Huesmann  Like the sheet metal idea. Rivet it in place and use AC tape and get a grommet.